# XML Schema is not considering one of its attribute

Tags: xml

I'm trying to read a text file using xml schema. The text file has few top unnecessary rows which I don't want to read. Here is the code I have in my schema

FileFormat="Delimited" Delimiter="" NoOfTopDataRowsToSkip="4" HasHeaderRow="true"

even though NoOfTopDataRowsToSkip is a valid attribute, it is still considering the rows. When I have just HasHeaderRow="true", it is not taking the first line. but NoOfTopDataRowsToSkip is not at all playing any role. How can make that the frst 4 rows should not be read.

Comment: FileFormat="Delimited" Delimiter=" " NoOfTopDataRowsToSkip="4" HasHeaderRow="true"

Comment: it got resolved though the code.